# DSLR vs CamCorders for video tutorials?

Tags: dslr, camcorder, video-capture

I'm planning to record video tutorials for a project of mine without compromising on the quality and I would like to know the best option to shoot them

Comment: This question is a bit broad. You might want to give us more details. What kind of tutorials do you want to make, what specifically do you need help with deciding in producing your tutorials? There are many factors in shooting videos. Asking for the best option is similar to asking "What is the best option to make music".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DSLRs tend to have much larger image sensors than camcorders, which tends to mean much less depth of field (DOF) for a given field of view.  Shallow DOF is great for isolating subjects from their background, but it's a nightmare when you actually want the subject and its context to be in focus together.

Most DLSR lenses have a limited zoom ratio and/or limited maximum aperture compared with camcorder zooms.  A typical DSLR kit (EOS 80D with 18-135mm f3.5-f5.6 zoom), can be equated to a 35mm equivalent of 29-216mm f3.5-f5.6 zoom lens.  A Canon Vixia G40 camcorder has a 35mm equivalent of a 26.8 - 576 f1.8-f2.8 zoom lens.  That's more than 2x longer at the long end with 2 f-stops more light-gathering ability.

Combine longer range, wider aperture, and more depth of field, and you can see why news organizations tend to send camcorders into the field.

On the other hand, depending on your subject and your aesthetic, you may prefer the shallow DOF look, such as this short video demonstrates: https://vimeo.com/100437145

Answer (score 1):

Another factor to consider in deciding between DSLR and Camcorder is the ergonomics. While the pictures from a DSLR have a nice cinematic look, they are harder to use.

As mentioned by Michael, the larger sensor gives you shorter depth of field, so anything other than static subjects can be challenging to keep in focus - and this is coupled with the fact that the displays are generally too low resolution to judge critical focus on-the-fly. So most people end up bolting on an external monitor.

The lenses are something else to consider: stills lenses often have the focus distances marked like "1ft—2ft—infinity". So a follow focus rig is a useful addition, meaning that you'll want rails to mount it all on. Most stills lenses also change speed as you zoom, so a close-up will be correctly exposed, but when you pull out for a wide shot you'll be a stop over.

And the shape of the camera is different. A DSLR is harder to hold steady while filming and looking at the screen, compared to a camcorder with a viewfinder that you jam onto your eye. So people often add shoulder rigs to them. So in addition to the camera you end up with a frankenrig with monitor, follow-focus, batteries external mics and recorder, and shoulder mount all hanging off it. If the look is worth it to you, then this might be acceptable, but if ease-of-use makes a difference this is a big minus for the DSLR.